# make gtk widget fill parent window

Tags: xml, gtk, alignment, pygtk

I am new to gtk programming (but experienced with python). I have a window that has a button widget child. What do I have to do if I want the button to completely fill the window?

By the way, this would be extremely easy to do with xml (fill-parent), is there anything similar to xml for gtk that is native?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you add a button to your window, it should actually fill it. That is the normal behaviour.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Without knowing what your program currently is, I can only give a general answer. There are two ways to interpret your first question; I'll answer both.

There are two types of containers in GTK+. The first, the *bin*, only has one child, and that child is automatically given the entire size of the parent to fill. GtkWindow, GtkScrolledWindow, GtkFrame, etc. are bins. If you add a widget directly to a GtkWindow, like in Mohsen's answer, it should fill the container.

The second type is the *layout container*. These are things like GtkBox and GtkGrid that let you pack multiple widgets into a neat layout. For these, GTK+ provides four widget properties on each individual widget to set: `hexpand`, `halign`, `vexpand`, and `valign`. The `h` and `v` determines which dimension the property applies to (horizontal or vertical). If `expand` is `TRUE`, the widget is given whatever space is left after non-expanding widgets are positioned using their *preferred size*. If `align` is `GTK_ALIGN_FILL`, the widget fills the given space. [This page](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.18/ch29s02.html) should explain better.

Note that with GTK+, a widget is given its size by its parent, not the other way around. A widget can *request* a given size to have, but the parent is free to ignore this. (GtkWindow is an example of one that doesn't ignre the size request; generally it will automatically size itself to make enough of its content visible unless explicitly overridden).

There IS an XML-based format for building GTK+ UIs. It's provided by the GtkBuilder type, and Glade produces these files so you don't have to write the XML format yourself. If you *do* want to write your UI file manually, each widget's documentation will have a section "GtkXxx as GtkBuildable" that shows how to write the XML.

Comment: Your link is broken. Any chance you can put the relevant bits in your answer itself?

Comment: Made it a permanent link instead; I'm not sure whether I can legally include that page's text and images verbatim in that answer.

Comment: That'll work. As an idea -- you don't need to copy/paste things. Since this question is about PyGtk, you could always write an example code snippet in Python to show the same idea, maybe with a couple screenshots. I realize that's significantly more work, so it's really up to you if you think it's worth it; I only suggested it at the time because I didn't realize that the content would still be hosted at all.

Comment: Right. The issue with the link was that it was listed as version `/stable/`, which means anything underneath that will change when a new GTK+ version comes out, and the exact location of that page within the generated documentation will vary as topics are added and deleted. In fact, this is the second time I've seen that page move; I guess I missed this spot when i was updating my personal links.

Answer (score 7):

By default, a widget will only get the same amount of space it requested, and not any less than its minimum size.

If you want a widget to fill the available space of its parent, you need to mark it as a expandable, using [`Gtk.Widget.set_hexpand()`](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Widget.html#Gtk.Widget.set_hexpand) and [`Gtk.Widget.set_vexpand()`](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Widget.html#Gtk.Widget.set_vexpand).

Answer (score 0):

By default any widget that added to many type of containers, fill all the parent:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

win = Gtk.Window()
btn = Gtk.Button("Ok")

win.add(btn)
win.show_all()
win.connect('destroy', Gtk.main_quit)

Gtk.main()
```

Comment: This is only true for GtkBin and derived.